# "Why not a show, while we're at it"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am reading *The Calculating Stars* by M.R. Kowal, and there is a piece I am not sure how to understand - I have two competing theories.

The situation: a woman hears very upsetting news; her husband tries to console her:
"I thought we might go dancing tonight".
Grinding her teeth, she replies:
"Why not a show, while we're at it".
It is unclear whether they went dancing afterwards.

My option A is to understand "show" as performance, perhaps cabaret. As in "let's take one step further and go watch a show instead of dancing". What I don't like in this interpretation - in my opinion, dancing is MORE fun than merely watching others dancing on stage.

Option B is to understand "show" as false pretense. As in "since we already pretend everything is fine, let's stick to that and go dancing".

Am I right with either option?

Comment: I'm sure your option A is the correct one. Whether you personally prefer dancing to going to the theatre is not relevant.

Comment: "Why not a show, while we're at it" indicates a show **as well as** dancing, and it's sarcastic. The woman doesn't want to go dancing, so she adds something else equally undesirable. The "while we're at it", which you didn't ask about, is actually the key to understanding the utterance.

Comment: ...the heavy sarcasm is also supported by *"Grinding her teeth..."* and she means "as well as dancing". She isn't offering an alternative, in fact she doesn't want to go at all.

Comment: The precise nature of "show" and "dancing" will depend a lot on the specific culture and time, which you don't specify, and Google says it's a science fiction novel so I'm not going to guess. Dancing has in the past been a very common recreational activity, which could be done in many clubs, bars, dancehalls, or even restaurants, while a show might require an actual theatre or similar venue. Today people in the UK or US don't go dancing in the same way as they did in the 1950s, so it maybe sounds odd.

Comment: @StuartF The book is in the alternative history genre; otherwise, it's realistic. The setting is the US in 1950s

Comment: @Andrew Leach '... and a trip to Vegas to round off the evening'.

Comment: It sounds like an argument about money to me. If they had restricted means then the cost of entry to a dance hall might be more than she thinks they can afford. Entry to a Broadway show would be even more extravagant.

Comment: Why would you think it means "instead". The literal meaning of "while we're at it" is "at the same time".

Comment: @Barmar It's because I can't imagine dancing and watching a show at the same time. Perhaps such things exist... Just not in my experience.